# Почему уведомления не приходят в фоновом режиме

Tags: java, android, android-notification, android-alarm-manager, android-push-notification

Проблема заключается в том, что уведомления не приходят, когда приложение закрыто на телефоне. Как только приложение открыто, то они начинают приходить. В приложение реализовано напоминание, который задает себе сам пользователь.
После чего на главное форме есть функция, которая проверяет, когда нужно запустить уведомление:

```
public void check_time(Calendar cal){
    if (info_persone.contains("key_time"));//проверяем есть ли совпадения
    {
        String buffer_text=info_persone.getString("key_time","");//копируем полностью в буффер текст
        TextView tt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);//это нужно только для теста
        tt.setText(info_persone.getString("key_time",""));
        for (int index=0; index < buffer_text.length(); index++) {
            if (buffer_text.substring(index,index+1).equals("-")) {//екуалс сравнивает == или != для этого не подходит
               cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt( buffer_text.substring(index+1,index+3)));//получаем часы
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt( buffer_text.substring(index+4,index+6)));//минуты
                startAlarm(cal,String.valueOf(test));//передаем кстати попробовать без теста чисто на индексе
                test++;
            }
        }
    }
}

 public void startAlarm(Calendar calendar, String action) {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent;//создаем слой
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;//это то что будет выполнять аларам бывает 3 вида сервис активити и брокаст
    myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,push.class);//присваиваем слой какой будет выполняться
    myIntent.setAction(action);//это нужно чтобы создавать много сигналов, короче тут стак слоев
    pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,myIntent,0);//объявление
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);//а тут мы ему говорим что делать читать в инете статью
    //Если говорить вкратце то тут что мы делаем запускаем активность через определенное время
}
```

В Push:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    String timeText = timeFormat.format(currentDate);
    mNotificationUtils=new NotificationUtils(context);//&#x41f;&#x43e;&#x434;&#x43a;&#x43b;&#x44e;&#x447;&#x430;&#x435;&#x43c; &#x43a;&#x43b;&#x430;&#x441;&#x441; &#x441;&#x435;&#x440;&#x432;&#x435;&#x440;
    String title = "Сообщение" + timeText;//пригодятся для того чтобы какой текскст или заголовок выводить
    String author =get_text();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(author)) {//проверям не пустые ли обьекты
        Notification.Builder nb = mNotificationUtils.
                getAndroidChannelNotification(title, "By " + author);//передаем в Нотификатион какой будет тайтл и текст уведомления
        mNotificationUtils.getManager().notify(101, nb.build()); //построение уведомления
    }
}
private String get_text(){
    main=new MainActivity();

    String buffer_text_2=main.info_persone.getString("key_type_food", "");
    String[] buffer_text=buffer_text_2.split("/");

    for(int i=0;i<buffer_text.length;i++){
        if(buffer_text[i].substring(0,1).equals("+")){
            buffer_text[i]=swap(buffer_text[i]);
            buffer_text_2=uptdate_key(buffer_text);
            main.info_ed.putString("key_type_food", buffer_text_2);
            main.info_ed.commit();
            return buffer_text[i];
        }
        else{

        }
    }
    return buffer_text_2;
}
private String swap(String buffer_text){
    char[] buf=new char[buffer_text.length()];
    buffer_text.getChars(0,buffer_text.length(),buf,0 );
    buf[0]='-';
    String buffer_text_rezault=new String(buf);
    return buffer_text_rezault;
}
private String uptdate_key(String[] key){
    String buffer_text="";
    for(int i=0;i<key.length;i++){
        buffer_text+=key[i]+"/";
    }
    return buffer_text;
}
```

Не обращайте внимание на комменты, писал их для себя, чтобы было понятнее))

Comment: Очень интересно решение данной проблемы. Аналогичная ситуация. Не могу победить приход уведомлений в фоне.

Comment: Как именно вы закрываете приложение? Если через `Force stop`, то работать точно не будет. Если просто смахиваете из списка открытых программ, то на большинстве стандартных прошивок должно работать. Также у вас `get_text()` абсолютно нерабочий - активити нельзя создавать вручную, это просто не будет работать.

Comment: Просто есть еще одно приложение где нету функции get_text() swap() и update_key(). Но он тоже не работает в фоновом режиме. Просто на телефоне захожу в диспетчер устройств и смахиваю